# How to save processes info (with cpu usage) to txt?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm on windows server 2012 R2 and I want to save detailed info of all running processes with details such as ram,cpu etc... to a text document. Is there any trick? I did a quick search and saw that you can get process info with the cmd tool using 'tasklist' but that doesn't list the cpu usage

Comment: this is a duplicate to one on stackoverflow with the answer, though they closed it there  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215756/windows-command-for-cpu-utilization-for-particular-service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is mentioned on this closed question here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215756/windows-command-for-cpu-utilization-for-particular-service

```
wmic path Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process get Name,PercentProcessorTime


C:\> wmic path Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process
get Name,PercentProcessorTime | findstr /i /c:chrome
chrome                  24
chrome#1                0
chrome#2                0
chrome#3                0
```

and he mentions

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206805/tasklist-cpu-usage